Unable to format the kafka topic data via pyspark
I am trying to push the data to Kafka topic via KSQL with the below code:
CREATE STREAM TEST01 (KEY_COL VARCHAR KEY, COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test01', PARTITIONS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

INSERT INTO TEST01 (KEY_COL, COL1, COL2) VALUES ('X',1,'FOO');
INSERT INTO TEST01 (KEY_COL, COL1, COL2) VALUES ('Y',2,'BAR');

Now when I am trying to run the below Pyspark code and trying to fetch the data and print on the console, it is printing the value along with some junk values
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Kafka_Test") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "test01") \
    .option("startingOffsets","earliest") \
    .load()

df.selectExpr("cast(value as string) as value").writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()

Output:

How can I format this much better?
As per Nimi's suggestion, I tried the below code where I fetched the schema from the schema registry but it is giving me null records. It is not fetching the actual values.
jsonSchema={"type":"record","name":"KsqlDataSourceSchema","namespace":"io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas","fields":[{"name":"COL1","type":["null","int"],"default":None},{"name":"COL2","type":["null","string"],"default":None}],"connect.name":"io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas.KsqlDataSourceSchema"}
df.select(from_avro("value", json.dumps(jsonSchema)).alias("sample_a")) \
    .writeStream.format("console").start()

Output:
+------------+
|    sample_a|
+------------+
|{null, null}|
|{null, null}|
|{null, null}|
+------------+


Finally, I was able to solve the problem using this blog. The author has well explained the concept.
The approach suggested by Nimi was right. There was this magic bytes trick that was missing and treating them the right way helped me to solve the issue.
Will have to read about magic bytes in much detail though.

Blog could've just used Confluent's HDFS sink and not needed to write any Spark code...

Very similar to what I wrote here - you are trying to parse a string - while you are writing an avro record.
In your code you specify:
CREATE STREAM TEST01 (KEY_COL VARCHAR KEY, COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test01', PARTITIONS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

You can see you specify VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'
That means you need to read the message as an avro record - not as a string.
from pyspark.sql.avro.functions import from_avro, to_avro

# `from_avro` requires Avro schema in JSON string format.
jsonFormatSchema = open("examples/src/main/resources/test01.avsc", "r").read()

df.select(from_avro("value", jsonFormatSchema).alias("test01"))\
.select("test01.*")\
.writeStream\
.outputMode("append")
.format("console")\
.start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()

Hope this helps!

I have tried your suggestion and made the changes to the original post. Please help me with that.
